# Jquery failed parsing XML 

Tags: jquery, air, xml-parsing

I am parsing youtube video feed in AIR app .
Using jquery to parse it.

```
    $(feed).find("entry").each(function()
    {
      var tit = $(this).find('title');
      alert(tit.text());
    }
```

It seems like after parsing `category`(category tag is closed a different way) it fails to parse rest of the doc.The above code successfully alerts text till `updated` tag.What can be the solution.

```
 <entry gd:etag='W/&quot;C0AMRn47eCp7ImA9WxRQGUw.&quot;'>
        <id>tag:youtube,2008:video:ZTUVgYoeN_b</id>
        <published>2008-07-05T19:56:35.000-07:00</published>
        <updated>2008-07-18T07:21:59.000-07:00</updated>
        <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
          term='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video'/>
        <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat'
          term='Shopping'/>
        <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat'
          term='parkas'/>
        <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat'
          term='People' label='People'/>
        <title>Shopping for Coats</title>
        <content type='application/x-shockwave-flash'
          src='http://www.youtube.com/v/ZTUVgYoeN_b?f=gdata_standard...'/>
        <link rel='alternate' type='text/html'
          href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTUVgYoeN_b'/>
        <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.responses'
          type='application/atom+xml'
          href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZTUVgYoeN_b/responses?v=2'/>
        <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.ratings'
          type='application/atom+xml'
          href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZTUVgYoeN_b/ratings?v=2'/>
        <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.complaints'
          type='application/atom+xml'
          href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZTUVgYoeN_b/complaints?v=2'/>
        <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.related'
          type='application/atom+xml'
          href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZTUVgYoeN_b/related?v=2'/>
        <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#mobile'
          type='text/html' href='http://m.youtube.com/details?v=ZTUVgYoeN_b'/>
        <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml'
          href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated/v/ZTUVgYoeN_b?v=2'/>
        <author>
          <name>andyland74</name>
          <uri>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/andyland74</uri>
        </author>
        <media:group>
          <media:title type='plain'>Shopping for Coats</media:title>
          <media:description type='plain'>
            What could make for more exciting video?
          </media:description>
          <media:keywords>Shopping, parkas</media:keywords>
          <yt:duration seconds='79'/>
          <yt:videoid>ZTUVgYoeN_b</yt:videoid>
          <media:player url='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTUVgYoeN_b'/>
          <media:credit role='uploader' scheme='urn:youtube'>andyland74</media:credit>
          <media:category label='People'
            scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat'>People
          </media:category>
          <media:content 
            url='http://www.youtube.com/v/ZTUVgYoeN_b?f=gdata_standard...'
            type='application/x-shockwave-flash' medium='video'
            isDefault='true' expression='full' duration='215' yt:format='5'/>
          <media:content
            url='rtsp://rtsp2.youtube.com/ChoLENy73bIAEQ1kgGDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp'
            type='video/3gpp' medium='video'
            expression='full' duration='215' yt:format='1'/>
          <media:content
            url='rtsp://rtsp2.youtube.com/ChoLENy73bIDRQ1kgGDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp'
            type='video/3gpp' medium='video'
            expression='full' duration='215' yt:format='6'/>
          <media:thumbnail url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/ZTUVgYoeN_b/2.jpg'
            height='97' width='130' time='00:00:03.500'/>
          <media:thumbnail url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/ZTUVgYoeN_b/1.jpg'
            height='97' width='130' time='00:00:01.750'/>
          <media:thumbnail url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/ZTUVgYoeN_b/3.jpg'
            height='97' width='130' time='00:00:05.250'/>
          <media:thumbnail url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/ZTUVgYoeN_b/0.jpg'
            height='240' width='320' time='00:00:03.500'/>
        </media:group>
        <yt:statistics viewCount='383290' favoriteCount='7022'/>
        <gd:rating min='1' max='5' numRaters='14763' average='4.93'/>
        <georss:where>
          <gml:Point>
            <gml:pos>21.37124437061831 -157.87353515625</gml:pos>
          </gml:Point>
        </georss:where>
        <gd:comments>
          <gd:feedLink href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZTUVgYoeN_b/comments'
            countHint='9416'/>
        </gd:comments>
      </entry>
```

Comment: What browser and what version isn't it working on? Also, that is not how you parse XML.

Comment: Not browser it is an Adobe Air App.Well let me know how to parse XML then , that is what i am asking here!

Answer (score 1):

You're right about the category tag...something weird was done, I noticed this when I copied and pasted google's youtube xml code that is registered as text because it is inside of `<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">[XML HERE]</pre>` into an XML parser; it too had trouble reading the category tags, which appeared to be improperly closed (even though they are).  I have a feeling that to fix the xml, a space between the forward slash and greater than sign would be necessary, ie

`<category scheme='[scheme_url]' term='[term_name]' />`

instead of what they have:

`<category scheme='[scheme_url]' term='[term_name]'/>`

But I guess that doesn't really doesn't help you solved your problem unless you are willing to fix the XML first.  However, I've used jQuery to parse the same feeds successfully.  It could be your initial `$.get` code, try using `$.getJSON` if you aren't already...let me see the remainder of your code if you still need help.

Otherwise, here's what I've been using, and it does work (as far as I know).  I am using it in a website and not Adobe AIR, but if you're using jQuery in AIR, jQuery is jQuery and it shouldn't matter (that's the best part about jQuery, imho).  Here's my code:

```
$.getJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/[insert_userName_here]/uploads?orderby=published&start-index=1&max-results=50&v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=?",
function(json){
    $.each(json.feed.entry,function(j,entry) {
        //Note: I wouldn't use an alert if you're reading from a big feed, as max-results is set to 50...
        alert(entry.title.$t);
    });
});
```

The code above reads any one user's feed containing all uploaded videos.  Hope this helps!